# JS element property settings not working with HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some javascript that sets up a hidden div for auto suggest and it works fine  when the doctype is set to : `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`

```
function editpartnumberInit() {
   /* Create Suggest Box */
                    suggestDiv=document.createElement("DIV");
                    suggestDiv.id="editpartnumbersuggestBox";
                    suggestDiv.className="suggest_results";
                    suggestDiv.style.visibility="hidden";
                    suggestDiv.style.width=400;
                    suggestDiv.style.zIndex="200";
                    document.body.appendChild(suggestDiv);
                    suggestDiv.style.position="absolute";
                    pos = suggestPos("editpartnumber", 400);
                    suggestDiv.style.top=pos[1];
                    suggestDiv.style.left=pos[0];
   /* Setup the event handler */
                    editpartnumberOldValue=document.getElementById("editpartnumber").value;
                    suggestAddTimer("editpartnumber", "editpartnumberOnchange()");
}
```

However if I change the doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` what happens on init is style.width, style.top, style.left will not set, there are no errors, even when I debug in chrome and try to set from the console, it just won't set.

Results with doctype 4.01:

`<div id="editpartnumbersuggestBox" class="suggest_results" style="visibility: hidden; width: 400px; z-index: 200; position: absolute; top: 321px; left: 421px;"></div>`

Results with HTML 5 simple doctype:

`<div id="editpartnumbersuggestBox" class="suggest_results" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 200; position: absolute;"></div>`

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Update: fixed thanks!

```
suggestDiv.style.width="400px";
pos = suggestPos("editpartnumber", 400);
suggestDiv.style.top=pos[1]+"px";
suggestDiv.style.left=pos[0]+"px";
```

Comment: JS `styles` only accept strings; change your integers to `200px` for example. You need to set the unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is here: `suggestDiv.style.width=400;`. In HTML5/CCS3 the width property can't be a simple number, it must have an unit.

If you change it to `suggestDiv.style.width='400px';` it should work.

the same applies here:

```
pos = suggestPos("editpartnumber", 400);
suggestDiv.style.top=pos[1];
suggestDiv.style.left=pos[0];
```

You must be sure that booth `pos[1]` and `pos[0]` includes the "px" after each number.